# How to sort alphabetically for country_select method in carmen-rails 1.0.0.beta 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using carmen-rails 1.0.0.beta 3 and for this I have used the following code:

```
<%= form_for(contact, remote: true, html: {class: 'popup-form'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :country, t('country') %>
    <%= f.country_select :country, include_blank: "Select" %>
<% end %>
```

This gives a result like this:
Aland Island,
Antartica,
Afghanisthan,
..........

But I want Afghanisthan to start the list in case of alphabetical order.
Can anyone give a solution to this sorting problem. It would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They've fixed this sorting bug, but perhaps they've not repackaged the gem or something. Try specifying the Git URL in your gemfile and I think it will work for you.

`gem 'carmen-rails', git: 'https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails.git'`